# Computer using hard drive in place of RAM?

Tags: memory

I am doing some school work about computer components and I came across this piece of information.

> you will find that if you don’t have enough RAM it can really bog down
>   your computer.  **This is because your operating system will try to use
>   your hard drive and your hard drive is a lot slower than the RAM**.

I don't understand this and don't want to learn the wrong facts, could someone please clarify this and if it is true or not?

Comment: It is true. Check out the Windows [PageFile (link)](http://lifehacker.com/5426041/understanding-the-windows-pagefile-and-why-you-shouldnt-disable-it)

Comment: TL;DR: RAM is memory. Hard drive is memory. RAM is *a lot* faster, but its capacity is more limited. When OS runs out of RAM it's better to use slower memory than announce failure. It's called paging.

Answer (score 1):

It it true indeed. It's called Paging, & your computer will do it automatically for you. For most casual users no intervention is required, but if your machine starts to page, yes it will slow it down.

From Wikipedia, this is just the opening paragraph...

> In computer operating systems, paging is one of the memory-management schemes by which a computer can store and retrieve data from secondary storage for use in main memory.[1] In the paging memory-management scheme, the operating system retrieves data from secondary storage in same-size blocks called pages. The main advantage of paging over memory segmentation is that it allows the physical address space of a process to be noncontiguous. Before paging came into use, systems had to fit whole programs into storage contiguously, which caused various storage and fragmentation problems.[2]
>
> Paging is an important part of virtual memory implementation in most contemporary general-purpose operating systems, allowing them to use secondary[a] storage for data that do not fit into physical random-access memory (RAM).

For the full article & many links, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging